# What perfromance improvement will I get by moving to lighttpd from Apache?

Tags: apache, lighttpd

I currently have a cluster of 4 Apache web servers which are used to serve up static files of up to 30Mb in size.  Generally, I can expect up to 5000 concurrent connections to these servers.  What performance improvement would I expect to get by moving this to lighttpd?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect it to handle the concurrency with much more ease and less memory overhead.  I've stopped deploying Apache pretty much everywhere I can.

You may also consider nginx for a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Apache with MPM](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mpm.html) with worker or event you probably won't see much of a difference. If you haven't moved to using them I would give that a try. There isn't really any problem with lighttpd though either. I think today it is just a matter of picking one and going with it.

If I where serving that type of file I would push it out to a CDN and not have to worry about it. There are plenty of cheap ones now like [CacheFly](http://www.cachefly.com/) and [Amazon's Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head:

1. Smaller memory footprint
2. Quicker file reads

Definitely check out the benchmark at their site, they provide a lot of information on this topic: http://www.lighttpd.net/benchmark